# OpenSSL client stuck in endless read

Tags: c++, linux, openssl

I am using [cpp-httplib](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib) to retrieve some data from a server using long polling (that is, the client will issue a request to the server, and the server will just keep the connection open until the required data is available or a timeout is reached).

The program is running on my raspberry pi, which sits behind a router that does *not* have an outgoing static ip address. Every time the ip is reassigned  (or, at least, close to that time point), my program breaks, in that the thread currently performing the poll will be forever stuck in `httplib::SSLClient::Get`, which is caused by a blocking `read()` syscall. Both server- and client timeouts are unable to do anything, while a connection close *should* make read immediately return 0, which is what i would have expected in this situation.

Inspecting the program with gdb shows the following:

```
(gdb) thread 2
(gdb) where
__libc_read (nbytes=5, buf=0x75608edb, fd=3) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c:26                          
__libc_read (fd=3, buf=0x75608edb, nbytes=5) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/read.c:24                          
0x76d1862c in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.so.1.1                                        
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

I am not doing anything (as far as I know) that could accidentally overwrite return addresses.

For comparison, a 'healthy' stack trace during a `SSLCLient::Get` can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/iyk4c8YG).

The actual code is quite a lot, but here's a short version that shows the same behaviour:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#define CPPHTTPLIB_OPENSSL_SUPPORT 1
#include "httplib.h"

void poll(httplib::SSLClient* c, char* path) {
  while (true) {
    auto response = c->Get(path);
    std::cout << response.body << std::endl;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc >= 3) {
    httplib::SSLClient client(argv[1], 443, 20);
    std::thread poll_thread(poll, &client, argv[2]);
    poll_thread.join();
  } else {
    std::cerr << "Usage: ./poll <host> <path>" << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
}
```

I can think of some workarounds that might or might not work, but I'd really like to know why and how this is happening in the first place.

Comment: did you try setting the keep_alive option?

Comment: Didn't realize that existed, I'm going to try that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just expanding on the keep_alive option I mentioned in the comment.

In the scenario you described, it seems possible that the underlying TCP socket connection was terminated in an unclean fashion.  I.e., you say the IP address was reassigned.

Ideally when there is a TCP socket termination, you want your code to exit out of any blocked read/poll operation.  That is what will happen for normal socket closures, e.g., say the remote process is killed, or the remote process just decides it is time to close.  But if the IP address of your host is changed .... I'm not sure there will necessarily be a low level TCP messages that says, to affect, this connection is now closed.    So the consequence for your program is that is can still hold a local socket (the local TCP endpoint), and not realise the connection has dropped.

This is where something like keep_alive.  The idea is that the kernel will send keep alive packets to keep testing if the connection is established; if these ever fail, then it can close the local socket (and so your blocking read, or blocking select, will return with some sort of end-of-stream error).

Separately to keep_alive, you can also consider application heart-beat messages (e.g., websocket has ping/pong).  In addition to ensuring the TCP connection remains established, it confirms whether the remote application is healthy.

Comment: Thank you, I'm now using keepalives directly with openssl and the unix sockets api, which seems to work fine